# Inserted var is not interpreted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following js snipped withing a PHP var

```
$put_in_foot_js_ready .= "


    $(document).on('click', '.playVideo', function() {
        var vID = $(this).attr('data-vid');

        $('body').append('<div id=\"gb_video\" class=\"modal fade\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><div class=\"modal-dialog modal-lg\"><div class=\"modal-content\"><div class=\"modal-body text-center\"><div class=\"pad5\"><button aria-label=\"Close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"close mar10btm mar5topNeg\" type=\"button\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">×</span></button></div><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ vID +'?rel=0&showinfo=0&hd=1&autohide=1&color=white\" width=\"859\" height=\"483\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div></div></div>');

        $('#gb_video').modal('show');
    });

";
```

Everything works great, except the value of the vID within src is not interpreted, even though when I put it in console.log(vID) I see correct value. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Rishi All this is withing PHP var that is using ""

Comment: You need to also escapped `$` i think

Comment: Did you try after escapping `$`

Comment: try eval(put_in_foot_js_ready)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do here is apply a better string type, which is an output buffer or use of [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) *(Example #2, but you will likely need some escaping on the `$` characters)*. That way, you can write everything out normally. I prefer the output buffer:

```
ob_start();
?>
$(document).on('click', '.playVideo', function() {
    var vID = $(this).attr('data-vid');
    $('body').append('<div id="gb_video" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body text-center"><div class="pad5"><button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close mar10btm mar5topNeg" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ vID +'?rel=0&showinfo=0&hd=1&autohide=1&color=white" width="859" height="483" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div></div></div>');
    $('#gb_video').modal('show');
});
<?php
$put_in_foot_js_ready   .=  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: This is a great idea. It did not fix the issue, but I like this buffer idea to avoid weird escaping. As far as the issue, this has something to do with the var. If I output it into console.log(vID) it shows correct value, but in code it still shows as '+vID+'.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying! Hold on

Comment: Where do you see it show the variable name but not the value?

Comment: The script works as I have it above, as in it will load the proper YouTube video extracting the vID and sending it to browser.

Comment: Yes, your code looks right to me. There's gotta be something weird going on on my side. I have a very similar function that picks the vars and inserts them into the code that is being appended as well. Strangely enough it does not work here... The most annoying kinda issue that defies all logic. Thanks for the help, like I said I'll change to using the buffered code for readability.